# Installing library orbitize on Python by Pycharm

Tags: python, installation, data-science

this is John and I've been stuck for a while trying to install the orbitize library in python. Some years ago I learned the basics of code in C and now I'm just diving into Python, so I don't understand very well all about how the language works. I'm coding using pycharm and the system is suggesting to me the next: "loosen the range of package versions you've specified" so I can fix the problem. Can someone there explain to me a bit how to do this?  Thanks so much for your help!